# Fixing Topology of FBX imports from cad cam

Tags: import, normals, topology, .fbx

I work doing industrial motion graphics and run into this problem all the time so I thought I would post to see if I'm not alone. Basically every model I import that companies give me turns out like this. Now I know the tricks of modifiers including remesh and shrinkwrap or even using the base mesh to make another mesh from scratch but it seems like there should be a better way...
[image]
[image]